# Multiple commands produce PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-privacy-settings, privacy-manifest

I am trying to build my app for iOS (using react-native), and I keep getting the error *Multiple commands produce PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy*.

I know where the error comes from, it's related to the fact that the Toast Pod has an PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file:

[image: Toast Pod]

But I also have one for my app, because otherwise Apple won't accept my app starting 1st of May 2024.

They are colliding, because the files are named the same, but Apple's guidelines are strict in that sense, the file must be named this way, so I cannot rename mine.

My temporary solution has been to delete the Toast privacy file (not just removing the reference, deleting it), but I feel there has to be an actual solution for this (like a way to merge both files).

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Thanks

Comment: My temporary solution has been to delete the Toast privacy file (not just removing the reference, deleting it) is it working ?